# Spring Boot BasicErrorController

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, spring-mvc

Spring Boot BasicErrorController 1.5.9

```
    @RequestMapping(produces = "text/html")
public ModelAndView errorHtml(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    HttpStatus status = getStatus(request);
    Map<String, Object> model = Collections.unmodifiableMap(getErrorAttributes(
            request, isIncludeStackTrace(request, MediaType.TEXT_HTML)));
```

Why is status not being read off the Response?  An HTTP Status is part of a Response, or am I missing something?

Reason I ask this is because getStatus() then does this:

```
protected HttpStatus getStatus(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Integer statusCode = (Integer) request
            .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
    if (statusCode == null) {
        return HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }
```

I now have a situation where the Response holds a 200 and the Request holds a 500.
Please advise what it is I'm missing?

Comment: Hey @Kondwani , will you please add a print statement before if(status ==null)  and check what is the exact value are you getting ?

Comment: As far as I can see, you're getting the status from the HttpServletRequest parameter "request". The way you can get to a status code is by HttpServletResponse.

Comment: Again, please note this is a class within Spring boot.  I debugged the value and it is null - there is no need to place print statements there.  My question was why this Spring boot class takes the status off the Request and not the Response.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/error/BasicErrorController.java